# how can I set system time from system_clock::time_point

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I set the system time of the platform (windows, linux, android) from a std::chrono::system_clock::time_point.

Comment: Erm.. there is no `chrono::system_time`. There's `system_clock`, but that's something different. And chrono is about time facilities, not date-time facilities.

Comment: I've right... I mean system_clock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the std::chrono facilities to set the time of any clocks. The best you can do is manufacture a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` to represent the chosen time, convert it to a `time_t` and then use that along with your platform's API to set the clock.

Comment: So for windows I've to convert from time_point to time_t, from time_t to tm, and from tm to SYSTEMTIME. And in unix enviorment which function set the system time ( UTC )?

Comment: `clock_settime` and/or `settimeofday` depending on the platform.

Comment: It's odd to mention converting it to `time_t`; that loses sub-second precision, and I'm not aware of any platform where the API to set the clock is directly in terms of that type. Instead just go directly from `time_point` to the relevant type for your system.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux I like the reference code from [Converting between timespec & std::chrono](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2019/01/31/converting-between-timespec-stdchrono/) for this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono; // for example brevity

constexpr timespec timepointToTimespec(
    time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds> tp)
{
    auto secs = time_point_cast<seconds>(tp);
    auto ns = time_point_cast<nanoseconds>(tp) -
             time_point_cast<nanoseconds>(secs);

    return timespec{secs.time_since_epoch().count(), ns.count()};
}

const char* timePointToChar(
    const time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>& tp) {
    time_t ttp = system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    return ctime(&ttp);
}

const time_point system_time = system_clock::now();
cout << "System time = " << timePointToChar(system_time) << endl;

const timespec ts = timepointToTimespec(system_time);
clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
```